# Need help setting up this MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB with the Node.JS driver.

My DB is arranged like this -

```
 {
    _id: ...,
    nfoo: ...,
    nbar: ...,
    nbaz: ...,
    items: [ 
    { completed:  true/false, ifoo: <number>, ibar: <number>, ibaz: <number>},
    { completed:  true/false, ifoo: <number>, ibar: <number>, ibaz: <number>}, ... ]
    <other properties>
    }
    {
    _id: ...,
    nfoo: ...,
    nbar: ...,
    nbaz: ...,
    items: [ 
    { completed:  true/false, ifoo: <number>, ibar: <number>, ibaz: <number>},
    { completed:  true/false, ifoo: <number>, ibar: <number>, ibaz: <number>}, ... ]
    <other properties>
    }
```

What I want to do is arrange this as a table with the headers like this

```
nfoo    nbar    nbaz    i_foobar    i_barbaz
```

Where nfoo, nbar and nbaz are all available at the top level document and i_xxxxxx will be calculated by iterating over the array of subdocs like this

```
i_foobar = (ifoo/ibar if completed=true) for item 1 + (ifoo/ibar if completed=true) for item 2 + ...
i_barbaz = (ibar/ibaz) for item 1 + (ibar/ibaz) for item2 + ...
```

So far I have figured out how to get just nfoo/bar/baz out of the documents

```
collection.find({}, 
        {
            projection: {
                _id: 0,
                nfoo: 1,
                nbar: 1,
                nbaz: 1
            }
        }).toArray((err, res) => {
        all_data = res
        // At this point my all_data is arranged like so [{nfoo: , nbar: , nbaz: }, {nfoo: , nbar: , nbaz: }] which makes it easy to make the table by just iterating over the data and separating the keys from the values
        let heads = Object.keys(all_data[0])
        generateTableHead(table, heads);
        generateTable(table, all_data);
    })
```

`generateTableHead()` and `generateTable()` are from [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/html-table/)

My question is how do I modify the collection.find statement to get i_foobar and i_barbaz items?

**edit: Some simplification**

`items` is an array of subdocuments

- `i_foobar` = sum of `(ifoo/ibar)` over all items where `completed=true`
- `i_barbaz` = sum of `(ibar/ibaz)` over all items

For example,

```
{
    _id: ...,
    nfoo: "foo",
    nbar: "bar",
    nbaz: "baz",
    items: [ 
    { completed:  true, ifoo: 20, ibar: 10, ibaz: 300},
    { completed:  false, ifoo: 50, ibar: 300, ibaz: 24}, 
    { completed:  true, ifoo: 40, ibar: 90, ibaz: 20} ]
    <other properties>
    }
```

For this document,

- `i_foobar` = 20/10 (because `completed=true` for item 1) + 0 (`completed = false` for item 2) + 40/90 (`completed=true` for item 3)
- `i_barbaz` = 10/300 + 300/24 + 90/20

Comment: Your description is hard to understand (could you simplify it, esp. concerning the calculation of i_foobar and i_barbaz?). But I assume you should consider aggregation for this query.

Comment: Simplified and added examples @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get what you are looking for with aggregation.  First unwind the `items` array, then group by the top level fields and use $cond with $sum for each item.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$items"},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        nfoo:{$first:"$nfoo"},
        nbar:{$first:"$nbar"},
        nbaz:{$first:"$nbaz"),
        i_foobar:{$sum:{$cond:["$completed",{$divide:["$ifoo","$ibar"]},0]}},
        i_barbaz:{$sum:{$cond:["$completed",{$divide:["$ibar","$ibaz"]},0]}}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to *iterate* over an array of subdocuments in mongo? Because I have already nested the relevant subdocs into an array in the parent doc; unwinding and then grouping back seem like extra steps. Forgive me if this seems like a dumb question, I don't have much database experience at all. 

In any case, I'll accept this answer if there aren't other better ones.

Comment: Also BTW, I don't think I need the conditional in ```i_barbaz:{$sum:{$cond:["$completed",{$divide:["$ibar","$ibaz"]},0]}}```

Comment: That's true, you could $match after unwinding so that you only consider the true ones.  As far as I know, there are not loops or iterators in the mongo query language, anything like that is done on the client side.